# Expand all folds created by vim-latex when opening a LaTeX file

Tags: folding, plugin-vim-latex

I want all my folds to be expanded when I open a LaTeX file. As per web search I added the following at the end of .vimrc

```
set nofoldenable
set foldlevelstart=99
set foldlevel=99
```

But even now its folding. I also added this is to my `ftplugin/tex.vim` but the results are the same. I am also using the plugin `vim-latex`.

Any idea on how to fix/ debug this problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81430/discussion-on-question-by-knightrider-nofoldenable-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

I checked with a minimal example the proposed solution from https://stackoverflow.com/q/16711143 and they work

1. Put the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

   ```
   setlocal foldlevel=999
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could define in `$MYVIMRC`:

   ```
   augroup latex
     autocmd!
     autocmd Filetype tex setlocal foldlevel=999
   augroup END
   ```

---

Question missed mentioning of plugin vim-latex which changes [how folding is done](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-folding.html) and the question has already been raised on stackoverflow 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/16711143/.
Please consider following advice for new questions https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15/1292.

Comment: While I respectfully agree with some of the comments, I have zero knowledge about the plug-in system in vim. In addition I did not even notice/remember the usage of vim-latex (I thought some of my other settings were interfering with the folds; hence I asked on help in "debugging" the problem). Once I found that vim-latex was the problem (thanks to the people in chat and my effort on debugging) I tried many things (see chat) none worked. Unfortunately I could not find the soln that you pointed.

Comment: For me only your soln2 is working and soln1 (which is the link which is supposed to have the answer) is not working (again some solns works only for some ppl which a genuine reason to repeat questions). But thanks to your answer, it provided one working solution (soln2)

Comment: Did you notice the subfolder **`after`** in the path specified in solution 1? It is not `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` which you mentioned in your question. In case of neovim, the path would be different. BTW both solutions are copied over. I just improved the second one by the recommendation from [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way – Chapt. 14](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html): put `autocmd` into an `augroup` and clear the group with `autocmd!`. Otherwise `autocmd`'s can pile up when sourcing your vimrc during runtime.

Comment: I use `tex.stackexchange.com` quite a lot. This site has a more strict policy how questions should be posted: questions only with a MWE are accepted so others can reproduce it easily. Most importantly the person who asks is forced to isolate the problem which e.g. helps to only read the needed parts of the relevant manuals. In your case it would have been `:h foldmethod` and `:h latex-folding`. Furthermore this allows you to search the web more precisely. IMHO the question on stackoverflow isolated the problem without the need for a mininmal vimrc & pointed to the right help page of vim-latex.

Comment: Just for the record: a link describing how ideally writing a question should be approached: https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1326/1292 (start from empty vimrc; following can be helpful for that https://superuser.com/a/1310444/161119)

Comment: That's reasonable. Yes I looked at the man page for foldmethod but that did not help much as the error was not there. Your suggestion of testing plugins in isolation is a good idea ( maybe normal debug first and then test in isolation). Even now I am confused with how `foldenable` was set  when I used `nofoldenable` and the `verbose set` is pointing to right location.

Comment: vim-latex will be sourced after your vimrc and will overwrite your `nofoldenable`. The order when vim sources different files on startup and when different autocmds are triggered is rather complex. But knowing the basic order (read `:h rtp` and print your value with `:set rtp?`) is helpful. In particular you should know the `:h after-direcotry`. You should move your tex-related folding settings to the after directory. IMHO the comment in the help *rarely needed* is incorrect. You need this to overwrite plugins which you want to leave as they are. Are you sure solution 1 does not work for you?

Comment: BTW vim-latex itself says in `:h Tex_AutoFolding` that you could `let g:Tex_AutoFolding = 0` in your vimrc which has the effect no (manual) folds are created automatically. Initialize folds when you want to fold with `\rf`. This speeds up opening tex files and possibly you do not need always folds. Sounds like a legit strategy. Furthermore, `:h foldenable` says `This option is set by commands that create a new fold or close a fold` which probably means that `verbose set` does not tell you which command has set it.

Comment: @Hotscke: if vim-latex overrides the config,  and `verbose set` cant point to the right location, is there any way to know where exactly the change was applied? Yes soln1 is not working (I tested once again). I thought of doing `let g:Tex_AutoFolding = 0` but then as you said I have to create folds myself. May be I can disable texfolding for higher level constructs such as  document and sections which would solve most of the problem.

Comment: @Hotscke: sorry found a mistake while doing soln1, it is also working now.

Comment: @knightrider thanks for checking sol1 again. I was worried that there is another configuration issue on your side. Regarding your question how to figure out where `foldenable` was changed:  `zM` changes `nofoldenable` to `foldenable` (see `:h zM`). This is used in the file [`vim-latex/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim`](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim#L161-L162). I have figured this out by reading `:h 'foldenable'` and searching for `/foldenable` in the help section `:h fold-commands`. Other commands which change `foldenable` are `zf, zc, zC, za, zA, zm, zn, zN`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigation. How did you figure out `vim-latex/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim` was the one setting `zM`? by greping the file? Is there a way to watch the a variable when a change occurs?

Comment: Yes, by grepping the file. Regarding watching variables: I do not know if there is a way. `:h debug-mode` or `'verbose'` and `'verbosefile'`  might be helpful to see what is going on. However, this generates a lot of output. BTW you can also raise an issue on https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex if you think that vim-latex should add an option for opening tex files with open folds. I do not use this plugin anymore and switched to vimtex.

Comment: may be I should also shift to vim-latex